# Loops Vs Meshes. Graph Theory in Electrical Engineering.

Tags: graph-theory

In class today, our professor was talking about loop analysis for circuits. You find a loop in the circuit, and you make the sum of elements on it. He said we use meshes [the smallest loops that dont surround any nodes] to analyze, because all other loops are unnecessary and more complicated.

As an example, he drew a grid like this:

[image: Grid]

In his, each of the lines had a resistor on it. There are 9 meshes, the inidividual boxes. There are many more loops though. The loops have to follow the line, and go from corner to corner. They cant cross a line more than once, and cant visit a corner more than once.

My question is this: how many loops are there that can be made on this grid? Is there a formula for how many loops there would be? Or does it have to be brute forced?

Is there a general formula for the number of cycles on a grid?

Comment: We can turn that drawing into a graph by letting the length 1 sides be the edges and the corners the vertices. Am I correct in assuming what you want is the number of cycles in the graph?

Comment: @Gamamal Yes. The number of simple cycles. I do admit I've barely had any experience in graph theory, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OEIS lists [the number of simple closed loops in an $m\times n$ lattice](http://oeis.org/A231829). No general formula is given. For a general graph, [computing the number of cycles is NP-hard](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr01/cs522/lecnotes/lec7.ps).

Comment: @Rahul This is exactly what I was looking for. You have answered my question. If you submit this as an answer, I'd gladly accept your answer, both verifying it, and also closing the question.